# Is there equivalent functionality for Universal Analytics behavioural flow in Google Analytics 4?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, google-analytics-4

Google Analytics: Universal Analytics behavioural flow was a fantastic tool and so simple to use.[image]

But I have had to change to Google Analytics 4 and this feature is not as clear. I cannot tell if it is even there any more?

[image]

I have been messing around for about an hour to try and reproduce picture one with no luck. Is it possible? To be clear 'Page title and screen name' 'Page title and screen class' just return my applications name. I can see the breakdown at the bottom of the screen but it is still not as useful as the original picture.

If it is not possible, is it OK to use a GA: UA property as well to see this behavioural flow? (Is it ok to use two tracking snippets of code for 2 properties?)

Comment: It is not the answer I was hoping for but for anyone interested this might help: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9973999?hl=en&utm_id=ad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible as of now, and it's one of the SEO community's largest complaints about the new (*cough cough...beta*) GA4 experience so far.

It's perfectly fine to use both, and I encourage it. I've had clients ask about moving to GA4 and for now I'm not moving anyone *completely* away from the universal (stable) analytics.

Here's [how to use both GA and GA4 in parallel](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9744165?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was doing something stupid. I would have assumed such an important feature would not have been dropped for the so called 'Newer' version. I was confident